# Adding a new document in Couchdb ( iriscouch ) POST request fails with Status 500

Tags: javascript, http, node.js, couchdb

A couple of months back,the code below worked perfectly and was used to add a new document in couchdb (iriscouch).

Now I'm getting a HTTP Status 500. Is there a workaround?

Code (in Node.js) :

```
var http=require('http');

var options = {
  host: 'sbose78.iriscouch.com',
  path: '/bosedb1',
  method: 'POST',

  headers:{
 'Content-Type':'application/json',
 'accept':'application/json'
   }
 };

var data={
   'servings' : 4,
   'subtitle' : "Delicious with fresh bread",
   'title' : "Fish Stew------"
};

var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
   console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
   console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
     var body="";

   res.on('data', function (chunk) {
     body+=chunk;
         console.log('BODY(inside listener):\n ' + body);

   }); 

  console.log('BODY (outside listener): ' + body);

});


req.on('error', function(e) {
  console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
});



 //write data to request body
req.write(JSON.stringify(data));
req.end();
```

---

The response:

```
    STATUS: 500
HEADERS: {"content-type":"text/plain","content-length":"239"}
BODY(inside listener):
 Internal routing error

Sorry, we cannot connect to the intended server.

We have just been notified of this problem. We will correct it as soon as possible.

Feel free to contact us if you have any questions: support@iriscouch.com
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like http://www.iriscouch.com/ is down at the moment:

```
Host not found: www.iriscouch.com
```

Comment: Tried out. Seems to be up, though.

Comment: +1 For maximum robustness, your code can retry if it gets a 500 since they are usually temporary (only a few seconds)

Comment: Yes, page is up again. Do you have the same problem, still?

Comment: Okay, things are fine now :-)

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using an abstraction layer, at least to do http?

- [request](http://github.com/mikeal/request)

Your codebase is going to have a lot of http code if you don't :)

Personally I wrote and maintain the node.js CouchDB client which is based on request, if you are curious about it you can find out more at [github](http://github.com/dscape/nano)